# Is g++ falsely throwing -Wnarrowing?

Tags: c++, c++14, gcc-warning, type-narrowing

This is GCC 7.4 running in C++14 mode:

```
        size_t i = 8;
        std::string strIndent { i, ' ' };
```

Looks fine, but I get back the warning:

```
AnalyticsDBI.cpp:538:48: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘i’ from ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
                 std::string strIndent { i, ' ' };
```

This is a compiler bug? I can't understand how the compiler could select to wrong overload. Should be constructor 2, as shown [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using braces prefers the list constructor (the one taking `std::initializer_list<char>` here, number 9 on cppreference). In this constructor, the elements are `char`, so it is a narrowing conversion. GCC will give you an actual error for this instead of only a warning if you compile with `-pedantic-errors`; this is not a conforming program because narrowing conversions are not allowed in braced initialization.

Comment: So am I forced to use parentheses if I want this constructor?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod, Yes, it is not uncommon to run into traps such as this one when using braces to call a non-list constructor of standard containers. (And you'd be among many to call the situation not ideal.)

Answer (score 3):

Compiling with clang shows that it's attempting to call the `initializer_list<char>` constructor in which `size_t -> char` is a narrowing conversion:

```
narrowing.cpp:5:26: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
        std::string strIndent { i, ' ' };
                                ^
narrowing.cpp:5:26: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
        std::string strIndent { i, ' ' };
                                ^
                                static_cast<char>( )
1 error generated.
```

Using () instead will call the constructor you want:

```
 std::string strIndent(i, ' ');
```